# Is there an authoritative catalog for rocket launch identifiers?

Tags: launch-sequence

For satellites there's [NSSDCA/COSPAR](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraftDisplay.do?id=2017-017A), but I'm unable to find something similar for [the launches of those objects](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spacex/32915199874/). I'm hoping I'm not looking for something that doesn't exist as I'm assuming launch groups cannot use just any name/id they whim to?

Comment: meta: trying to use proper data https://github.com/PixnBits/multiplanetary-data/issues/2

Comment: So you're looking for an archive of launch mission data, as in telemetry from the launcher? There's no public archive of that. You can find telemetry for some individual missions (the Apollo launches come to mind), but mostly this data is considered proprietary and not published.

Comment: While that would be even better, I'm looking just for an authoritative specification/list/group on naming launches. Maybe something like `US-AP11`.

Comment: I doubt that exists. A launch needs maybe an unique identifier by launch range (but I haven't seen anything that qualifies as that), not a worldwide unique ID.